# Rotating the area between two functions around the x-axis: two methods, one correct and one is not. Why?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am taking a class in basic calculus and I came across a problem on rotation volumes that when solved with one (to me seemingly valid method) gives incorrect results. I am curious as to why and I hope someone here will be able to explain why my first method does not work.

**The problem:**
Calculate the volume  of the rotational body that arises when the area limited by the line $y = x$ and the parabola $y = x^2$ is rotated around the x-axis.

**My first (incorrect) solution:**
Use a definite integral with upper and lower bounds where the line and the parabola intersect.
$x^2 = x$
gives $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 1$

My idea was that since radius $R$ for the rotation is equal to the distance in $y$ between $y = x$ and $y = x^2$ I could insert $x-x^2$ as $R$ in $A = \pi R^2$

Using the [disc method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration) and $x_1$ and $x_2$ as as our lower and upper bounds gives
$V = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\pi(x-x^2)^2dx$

I don't like that integral so I wanted to expand the $(x-x^2)^2$ factor by using the formula:
$(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$

This resulted in:
$V = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\pi(x^2+x^4-2x^3)dx$

$\pi$ is a constant so I moved it out of the integral, and split the integral up resulting in:
$\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^2dx + \pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^4dx - \pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}2x^3dx$

Integration gave the following:
$\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^2dx = \pi\frac{x^3}{3}|_0^1 = \pi(\frac{1^3}{3}-\frac{0^3}{3}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$
$\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^4dx = \pi\frac{x^5}{5}|_0^1 = \pi(\frac{1^5}{5}-\frac{0^5}{5}) = \frac{\pi}{5}$
$-\pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}2x^3dx = -\pi\frac{x^4}{2}|_0^1 = -\pi(\frac{1^4}{2}-\frac{0^4}{2}) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$

Adding these together gave me the incorrect answer:
$V = \frac{\pi}{30}$

**The second (correct) solution:**
Again using the disc method with lower and upper bounds $x_1$ and $x_2$ but expressing $V$ as the difference between the rotational volume of $y = x$ and $y = x^2$ gives:
$V = \pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(x)^2dx - \pi\int_{x_1}^{x_2}(x^2)^2dx = \pi\frac{x^3}{3}|_0^1 - \pi\frac{x^5}{5}|_0^1 = \frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{5} = \frac{2\pi}{15}$

**The question**:
Why did the first solution not work?

Comment: $y=x$ is a cone when rotated, when you remove the volume of $y=x^2$ from $y=x$ you get the volume of the cone with its centre part ($y=x^2$) removed,  plot $y=x-x^2$ and check its volume when rotated, the two figures are not the same

Comment: Why would the figures looking different have that severe of an impact when rotating? The end goal is to find a volume, which is a number. The figure that arise from $y=x-x^2$ represents the difference between $y=x$ and $y=x^2$. The same difference that we get when we remove the volume of $x^2$ rotated with the second integral in the second method.

Comment: In your first solution you set $(a-b)^2=a^2-b^2$

Comment: Where did I do that?

Comment: When You subtracted the radii and squared the difference,

Comment: I spotted an error in the Area formula. Should be $A = \pi R^2$ not $A= \pi R$. Was this what you commented on?

Comment: No, $(x-x^2)^2$ is not equal to $x^2-x^4$

Comment: Where did I write that? I wrote $(x-x^2)^2 = x^2 + x^4 - 2x^3$

Comment: I mean in your first attempt you directly subtracted $(x-x^2)^2$, in your second attempt you did $(x)^2-(x^2)^2$ and clearly these two expressions are not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine a pie which has a circular cut around the middle of the pie.  The cut is halfway between the center and the crust.  There is an inner circle and an outer ring and each of them has the same 'height'.  The outer ring contains much more pie because the rotation of something further from the center traces out more volume than something close to the center.

To put numbers to it, assume a cylindrical pie with a radius of 8 inches and a height of 1 inch.  The inside cylinder will have volume 1*pi*(4)^2 = 16pi.  The entire pie will have a volume of 1*pi*(8)^2 = 64pi.  So by subtraction, the outer ring will have 48pi volume.

Your first attempt puts the height to be rotated right next to the center instead of further away, so the volume ends up smaller.